# Database,Table creation,insertion in sqllite in android-The application(process com.data)has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-sqlite

hi i used this code to create a database,create table and inserting value. but it shows `The application(process com.data)has stopped unexpectedly`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //This Button object get button name
         Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
                  try
                  {
                      //This EditText Get Textboxs Values
                  EditText edittxt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                  EditText edittxt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                  EditText edittxt3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                      //This is Create Database in you Data Folder
                      db = openOrCreateDatabase( "aahussain.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null );
                      // This String Create table in database
                    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists info (name VARCHAR(255),Email VARCHAR(255),phone VARCHAR(255))";
                    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
                    //This is String Insert Data in your Table
                    String    Query =    "insert into info (name,Email,phone) values ('" + edittxt1.getText() + "','" + edittxt2.getText() + "','" + edittxt3.getText() + "')";
                    db.execSQL(Query);
                  }
                  catch(Exception e)
                  {    // This is Toast Catch your Exceptions
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                  }    // now DB Close
                      db.close();
              }
            });
    }
```

Comment: can you post your error log?

Comment: this is the link for error log http://i40.tinypic.com/294mqkx.png and second image link is http://i44.tinypic.com/25hha55.png

Comment: @VengadeshK  db.close() should be never called in onCreate(). You can place it in onStop(). Plus open your database in write mode for inserting values.

Comment: How to change the mode

Answer (score 0):

SQL3 supports 5 types of datatype:

NULL. The value is a NULL value.

INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Please change your create database syntax like this:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists info (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, Email text, phone text)";
```

You have to open the database in write mode for inserting any value.

Close your database on `onStop()` of activity.

Change this:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase( "aahussain.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY ,  OPEN_READWRITE );
```

Change this :

```
//This EditText Get Textboxs Values
EditText edittxt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText edittxt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText edittxt3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
                  try
                  {

                      //This is Create Database in you Data Folder
                      db = openOrCreateDatabase( "aahussain.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null );
                      // This String Create table in database
                    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists info (name VARCHAR(255),Email VARCHAR(255),phone VARCHAR(255))";
                    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
                    //This is String Insert Data in your Table
                    String    Query =    "insert into info (name,Email,phone) values ('"
                    + edittxt1.getText().toString() + "','" +            edittxt2.getText().toString() + "','" + edittxt3.getText().toString() + "')";
                        db.execSQL(Query);
                      }
```

I will suggest you to read android tutorials.

Comment: Type affinity in SQLite means that VARCHAR(255) will be created as TEXT. So whilst the create statement should arguably be updated, it's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Nigelk . db.close() should be never called in onCreate(). It should be there in onStop().

Comment: For OPEN_READWRITE it asks for create constant 'OPEN_READWRITE' in type MainActivity...

Comment: @VengadeshK OPEN_READWRITE is defined in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase. you can use SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE. Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#OPEN_READWRITE

Comment: Even if i create constant 'OPEN_REAWRITE' in type MainActivity it shows the application was stopped unexpectedly... @ZohraKhan